# How to pass input data to a function in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am transforming a React class application to React hooks, but I am stuck in this part, I want to send data from the input to a function but It just does not work, in React classes everything worked with the use of "this" but I removed it. I tried everything, but I am starting to think that It does not work in React hooks, in that case how can i make it work in react hooks? Thanks.

This is the part of the code where I am focused, the username, password and remember error say that they are undefined. If you take a look to the inputs. I am invoking "innerRef" to take each value.

```
const handleLogin = (event) => {
    toggleModal();
    alert(`Username: ${username.value} 
    Password: ${password.value} Remember: ${remember.checked}`);
    event.preventDefault();
}


<Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} toggle={toggleModal}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggleModal}>Login</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={handleLogin(event)}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="username">Username</Label>                                         
                    <Input type="text" id="username" name="username"
                        innerRef={(input) => username = input} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>                            
                    <Input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                        innerRef={(input) => password = input} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" name="remember"
                        innerRef={(input) => remember = input} />
                        Remember me
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <Button type="submit" value="submit" color="primary">Login</Button>
            </Form>
        </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Can I ask some question. What is `innerRef`. I don't understand innerRef. 
In terms of hooks, there is `useRef()` for ref

Comment: InnerRef is a property of the Input component which is from reactstrap.

Comment: @StarkJeon If you have another solution you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like there are several issues with your code. The ones that I can see at the moment are:

- In `handleLogin`, you should first prevent the default event and do what you want to do afterwards (call `event.preventDefault()` as the first thing in that function, that is)
- When you assign event handlers with params (like you did in `Form` components' onSubmit event), assign it like this `onSubmit={ event => handleLogin(event) }` or else they will get called instantly. You don't want that, you want them to get called when the event happens.
- Don't understand the `innerRef` bits in your code, they look quite problematic, but a more traditional way of handling form input with hooks would be to leverage `useState` hook to define state variables and setters for them and updating these states when the relevant input change. I mean something like this:

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

...

<Input 
   type="text" 
   id="username" 
   name="username"
   onChange={ e => setUsername(e.target.value) }/>
```

Comment: sorry if you see some mistakes, there were attempts to solve the problem, but of course i will solve it, thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

React Functional Components don't need `this` keyword.
When you want to send input to a function there's no need to use refs - that's usually reserved for extreme cases and is not "the react way" You're better off doing a controlled input via state (call a useState hook at the top of your component and then make an onChange function that passes the value of input to setState). I would advise to have a look at the official react docs and do a bit of research about functional components. Once you get the hang of hooks, they are a breeze to work with.

Comment: thank you very much for the advice Raf, I'll do it.